# debugging - Steping function to function in all modules

Tags: python

I am debugging a python module which import modules in addition.

[main.py]

```
import module1

def main():
    param = 'A'

    module1.func1(param)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[module1.py]

```
def func1(arg1):
    print(arg1)
```

So what i am hoping to get is

```
PROMPT> python -m pdb main.py
(pdb) <theCommand>
calling main()
(pdb) <theCommand>
calling module1.func1(param = 'A')
(pdb) <theCommand>
calling print(firstArg = 'A')
A
```

I remember this can be done in gdb for debuggin c source.
Can this be done pdb ?

EDIT1: step does not work

```
-> import module1
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1559)_find_and_load()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1561)_find_and_load()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1562)_find_and_load()
(Pdb) 
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(266)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(270)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(271)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(272)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
KeyError: 'module1'
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(272)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(273)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(274)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(275)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(276)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(279)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(181)__init__()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(182)__init__()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(183)__init__()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(184)__init__()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(185)__init__()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(186)__init__()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(187)__init__()
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(187)__init__()->None
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(280)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(282)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(283)_get_module_lock()
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(283)_get_module_lock()->_ModuleLock('...39858433548816
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1564)_find_and_load()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1565)_find_and_load()
(Pdb) 
--Call--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(201)acquire()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(207)acquire()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(208)acquire()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(209)acquire()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(210)acquire()
(Pdb) 
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(211)acquire()
```

I dont know what to do with it.

EDIT 2: Thats how i debug in c using gdb.
[main.c]

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void func2(char * str)
{
    NULL;
}

int func1(int a)
{
    int b = 0;
    b = b + 1;  // useless statement

    func2("this is a string");
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0 ;
    return func1(a);
}
```

now gdb a.out

```
(gdb) break func1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004c5: file main.c, line 10.
(gdb) break func2 
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4004b8: file main.c, line 6.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 3 at 0x4004e7: file main.c, line 19.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./a.out 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Breakpoint 3, main () at main.c:19
19      int a = 0 ;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, func1 (a=0) at main.c:10
10      int b = 0;
(gdb) 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, func2 (str=0x400584 "this is a string") at main.c:6
6   }
(gdb) 
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 29249) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

(ps. I have not used gdb for a while so I might have sound confused earlier. All good now.)

Now I tried do the same with pdb.

```
> ./main.py(3)<module>()
-> import module1
(Pdb) n
> ./main.py(5)<module>()
-> def main():
(Pdb) break module1.  
module1.__builtins__      module1.__doc__           module1.__initializing__  module1.__name__          module1.func1             
module1.__cached__        module1.__file__          module1.__loader__        module1.__package__       module1.py:               
(Pdb) break module1.func1
Breakpoint 1 at ./module1.py:3
(Pdb) c
> ./module1.py(4)func1()
-> print(arg1)
(Pdb) c
A
The program finished and will be restarted
> ./main.py(3)<module>()
-> import module1
(Pdb)
```

So instead of

```
> ./module1.py(4)func1()
```

I was hoping to see something like this

```
> ./module1.py(4)func1(arg1 = 'A')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `s(tep)` command. It will step into functions (unlike `next`, which strictly advances to the next line if possible).

Comment: I dont want see everything into a function. Just functions. And Also it does not go through external module.

Comment: What? Your prompt clearly shows you want to do stepping...how does `s` not do what you want? Have you tried it? What's wrong with it?

Comment: I am still new to debbuging, but when press s in pudb it stopped at every line including every assignment or conditoin statement. So this was not what I had in mind, I only it to stop when calling a function.